# Bluetooth device (phone) listed twice with different icons in Windows 10 BT settings

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

When I pair an Android phone to my PC, the phone is showing twice in Windows' "Bluetooth & other devices" settings screen:

[image: screenshot Windows' Bluetooth settings]

I'm not sure why this happens, or what does the second icon (with two rectangles) should mean? Either of them can be unpaired, with the other record staying in the list.

Also, when I try to enumerate in C# over the paired devices (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51530152/997940)), I only get one record for each of these duplicated-devices.

Comment: These are two different device types. *what does the second icon (with two rectangles) should mean?* I think it is phone's memory accessible like flash-drive.

Comment: They're the same device but it indicates that is assigned to 2 different purposes (phone, file transfer). Can't confirm what the phone symbol means though.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I thought it might mean different purposes, but then I can't understand why: 1. it doesn't say so explicitly (no tooltip on mouse hover), 2. can unpair one without the other, 3. on the phone itself, the PC is listed as BT-paired only once.

Comment: It usualy appears if your phone acts as BLE device. Also it may be because of A2DP (audio) profile and other profiles. You can check what it exactly mean if you take a look in Device Manager to find out which devices (drivers) were installed for the phone.